# Get object from array with latest value in date property?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to get the object from an array that has the latest/largest value in the date property. Is there a nice way to do this?

```
[
  {
    "Address": 25,
    "AlertType": 1,
    "Area": "North",
    "Date": "2019-02-01T00:01:01.001Z",
    "Value": -1
  },
  {
    "Address": 26,
    "AlertType": 1,
    "Area": "West",
    "Date": "2016-04-12T15:13:11.733Z",
    "Value": -1
  },
  {
    "Address": 25,
    "AlertType": 1,
    "Area": "North",
    "Date": "2017-02-01T00:01:01.001Z",
    "Value": -1
  }
          .
          .
          .
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using Reduce (O(n)):**

```js
var data = [{    "Address": 25,    "AlertType": 1,    "Area": "North",    "Date": "2019-02-01T00:01:01.001Z",    "Value": -1  },  {    "Address": 26,    "AlertType": 1,    "Area": "West",    "Date": "2016-04-12T15:13:11.733Z",    "Value": -1  },  {    "Address": 25,    "AlertType": 1,    "Area": "North",    "Date": "2017-02-01T00:01:01.001Z",    "Value": -1  }]

console.log(
  data.reduce((a,b)=>new Date(a.Date).getTime() > new Date(b.Date).getTime()? a : b, {})
)
```

---

**Sorting (O(n log n)):**

```js
var data = [{    "Address": 25,    "AlertType": 1,    "Area": "North",    "Date": "2019-02-01T00:01:01.001Z",    "Value": -1  },  {    "Address": 26,    "AlertType": 1,    "Area": "West",    "Date": "2016-04-12T15:13:11.733Z",    "Value": -1  },  {    "Address": 25,    "AlertType": 1,    "Area": "North",    "Date": "2017-02-01T00:01:01.001Z",    "Value": -1  }]

console.log(
  data.sort((a,b)=>new Date(b.Date).getTime() - new Date(a.Date).getTime())[0]
)
```